# How do i get the image download URL in database in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to get the image download link and store it in *Firestore* database. Bellow is the function to upload the image to Firebase storage, if the function is wrong can you please explain why and write me a function?

```
File _image1;
Future uploadPic() async {
    StorageReference reference = storage.ref().child('image');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_image1);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    imageUrl1 = url;
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add return to the function to retrieve the output(url)

```
File _image1;
Future uploadPic() async {
    StorageReference reference = storage.ref().child('image');
    StorageUploadTask uploadTask = reference.putFile(_image1);
    StorageTaskSnapshot taskSnapshot = await uploadTask.onComplete;
    String url = await taskSnapshot.ref.getDownloadURL();
    imageUrl1 = url;
    return url;
  }
```

From this you can call the then function,

```
uploadPic().then((value)
            {
        DocumentReference docRef = 
        Firestore.instance.collection('collectionname').document(documentid);
             docRef.setData({'pic' : value},merge:true)
             });
```

Comment: thanks man. really man you saved me. @kingmort. i really appreciate it